# Magento Logged out customer + Pesistent behavior

Tags: magento

Is it possible to change the default Magento's behavior on working with persistent? 
I need such logic (Persistent enabled 'On' in admin): when customer click "LogOut" then header block must be exactly like for a guest.
i.e it must show default welcome message and top menu must contain 'LogIn' link. But after customer relogin is must show persistent user's data.
By default Magento in this case (for logged out customer) show 'Wellcome ' message with link to erease persistent cookie and there is not 'LogIn' link in top menu.

Please help me with implementation algorithm.

Thank you.

Comment: "Please write all my code for me". What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, Mark! No, I just want to know if it possible. I need an idea and approximate algorithm. (for eaxample, I need to rewrite some methods in Persistent and modify some layout files). Thank you.